# Is dual is safe

Tags: dual-boot

I have windows 10 pc and I have 4gb ram and it has Intel i5 3gen processor. I want to dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 20lts will it work or not

Comment: Please see: [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/221835) Nothing in your question suggests that you would be unable to install Ubuntu in dual boot configuration.  We kindly ask that you search and research before asking. You may find that your questions are already answered. Doing research first prevents us from having to repeat obvious or basic information. If you still have questions, it's much easier to compose an successful/answerable question when you've already done research.

Comment: There is also an [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). This is a good resource to go over every step of the installation step-by-step. It does not cover dual boot configuration directly, but it does link to a reliable source in a tool tip at the relevant time during installation where you'd set up dual boot.  (Step 6 in the tutorial)